# Splitting up a list into a 2D list using tabs and spaces

Tags: python, list, split, strip

I am trying to split up a python list into a 2D list starting with the following

```
testList = ["Color Blue»Temperature Warm»Gender Male",
            "Color Green»Temperature Warm»Gender Female"]
```

Where » is a tab character and the attributes (color, temp, gender) have a tab before them and the specifics (blue, warm, male) have a space before them.

I would like to ignored the attributes and create a 2D list like

```
newList = [["Blue", "Warm", "Male"], ["Green", "Warm", "Female"]]
```

but I cannot figure out how to do this using the `split()` or `strip()` string methods.

Comment: `re.sub(r"\b\w+ (\w+)", r"\1", " ".join(testList))`

Answer (score 2):

If the attribute names and values are always single-worded, you can get every odd (indexing starts from 0) word in the string:

```
>>> testList = ["Color Blue Temperature Warm    Gender Male", "Color Green  Temperature Warm    Gender Female"]
>>> print([item.split()[1::2] for item in testList])
[['Blue', 'Warm', 'Male'], ['Green', 'Warm', 'Female']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's (another) way to do it:

```
testList = ["Color Blue Temperature Warm    Gender Male",
            "Color Green    Temperature Warm    Gender Female"]

newList = [[subitem.split()[-1] for subitem in item.split('\t')]
                                    for item in testList]

print(newList)  # -> [['Blue', 'Warm', 'Male'], ['Green', 'Warm', 'Female']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution relying on attribute names ("*Color*", "*Temperature*", "*Gender*") and the [Alternative regular expression module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)(to allow overlapping matches):

```
import regex as re

testList = ["Color Blue Temperature Warm    Gender Male", "Color Green Temperature Warm    Gender Female"]
items = re.findall(r'Color (\w+)\b Temperature (\w+)\b[\s\t]*?Gender (\w+)', ' '.join(testList), overlapped=True)

print([list(m) for m in items])
```

The output:

```
[['Blue', 'Warm', 'Male'], ['Green', 'Warm', 'Female']]
```